# github approval policies to ignore certain commits that has trivial changes when branch restriction is enabled

Tags: github, git-branch, branching-and-merging, pull-request

is there a way for Github branch restriction policies to ignore certain commits that has trivial changes in the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't.  You would need to be able to provide some definition as to what constitutes a trivial change, and there is no universally accepted definition that GitHub can use to implement this.

If you want to have such a policy, you can either have a bot that approves such changes and allows them to be merged, or you can see if using a GitHub Action to automatically merge such changes is possible.